# функция,принимающая объект и метод в python

Tags: python

нет ли такой встроенной функции в python,которая принимала бы в качестве аргументов
объект и метод и вызывала бы его(типа setattr,только вместо названия поля - метод)?

Comment: `getattr(объект, 'имя_метода')()`

Comment: @andreymal Это стоило бы оформить ответом.

Comment: getattr(объект, 'имя_метода')() вроде сработало,но как это работает?